# CONCATENATE syntax error "unable to interpret text-cb1"

Tags: checkbox, concatenation, abap

I've been trying to make a dynamic col for a select. it's just for learning.
I've made a selection screen with some select-options and checkbox parameters. whenever i have a checked checkbox i want to concatenate a string to my lineselection var.

```
lineselect = ' CARRID CONNID'.
SELECTION-SCREEN BEGIN OF BLOCK block1 WITH FRAME TITLE text-001.
[...]
SELECTION-SCREEN END OF BLOCK block1.

IF cbcofr EQ 'X'. "where cbcofr is checkbox
CONCATENATE text-cb1 INTO lineselect SEPARATED BY space. "where text-cb1 is 'CONTRYFR
ENDIF.
```

When i check for error the compiler just says "Unable to interpret "text-cb1". possible cause: incorrect spelling or comma error."

Is not about text-cb1 , i've tried with string 'COUNTRYFR' and says the same thing. I don't get where my error is.

Comment: :) silly me. I was concatenating just one object with noting into lineselect. And i rush here quickly ...

    CONCATENATE text-cb1 lineselect INTO lineselect SEPARATED BY space.
sorry for bothering.

Comment: You may delete your question, when you already found your mistake.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The syntax for concatenate is as follows:

```
CONCATENATE c1 c2 [... cn] INTO targetc [SEPARATED by sep].
```

or

```
CONCATENATE lines of itab into targetc [SEPARATED by sep].
```

As you have already noted, you need at least two source variables to concatenate.

Full documentation can be found [here](http://help.sap.com/abapdocu_702/en/abapconcatenate.htm)

As of Netweaver release 7.02 you can also do this:

```
targetc = c1 && [c2 ... && cn].
```

In this case, you lose the "separator" functionality, though.

Comment: The concatenation with ampersands works only for string literals, and not for variables, so it's not really a valid solution.

Comment: @mydoghasworms Gah, you made me look it up! As of Netweaver Release 7.02, it works for variables as well.

Comment: Well, then I humbly concede :-) Thanks for the info!